# Magento 2.4 Invoice - Templates

Tags: magento2, invoice, pdf

Does anyone know if there is anywhere that has a selection of Free PDF Invoice templates that is compatible with Magento 2.4.3?

I need to show each custom attribute on a new line, I would also like like to capture another product attribute (Delivery Time) at the time of order within this area also.

I would also like to add the customer comment during checkout and also some custom text at the bottom of the invoice such as customer signature. I have done this before in Magento 1.9 but it looks to be completely different in 2.4. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Magetrends Pdf extension but its paid.

It is very useful in customising the Pdf templates for Invoice, shipments and Orders

https://www.magetrend.com/magento-2-pdf-invoice